# Formatter Using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, formatting, heatmap

I'm using a custom formatter in creating a data label:

```
formatter: function() {
   return this.point.name + '<br>' + this.point.id;
}
```

which produces:

> SomeName
>
> SomeID

While the top line seems to be centered with respect to my segment / block, the bottom line does not. More generally, would it be possible to format the top and bottom line separately?

I would like the top line and bottom line to both be centered, but the top line to be significantly larger than the bottom line. When I edit the fontSize property under style, under dataLabels, under series it affects both lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional html elements in the formatter function and then style them to your heart's content.  Make sure you have `useHTML:true`.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/qqqpmpLm/

CSS:

```
.labelName {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.label {
  color:red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

dataLabels:

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return '<div class="label"><span class="labelName">'+this.point.name + '</span><br>' + this.point.id + '</div>'
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks!! Weird that it wasn't working when I put the formatters within the span tag directly instead of first putting it into a css. Maybe I had a typo or something...